# Programmatically import a form in Access

Tags: c#, ms-access

I need to write an automatic updater for a MS Access database and I need it to Delete a specific Form and then Import a new one from another database.  If possible, how would you accomplish this in C#?

Comment: Would it not be easier to just replace the entire .MDB file? Or, does this .MDB contain both forms, reports, etc. AND data?

Comment: yea, I have about 100 of these databases that are in active use with loads of data. -OP

Comment: Are these databases ahsred or only ever one user in them at a time?  If shared I'm surprised they haven't corrupted or had other wierd errors.   See the "Splitting your app into a front end and back end Tips" page at http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/splitapp/ for more info.  See the free Auto FE Updater utility at http://www.autofeupdater.com/ to make the distribution of new FEs relatively painless..   The utility also supports Terminal Server/Citrix quite nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do so using Docmd.CopyObject method (of Access.Application object)

Comment: Welcome, Alex! Glad to see yet another expert Access developer arrive at SO.

Comment: Hey, nice to see you here.  Hmmm, I didn't realize you could do this.   I'll have to check that out someday.